# Iptables string matching to block ips behind Reverse Proxy?

Tags: nginx, firewall, iptables, system-administration

I have nginx server behind reverse proxy (Cloudflare) and want to block ips based on the xforwarded ip sent in the header.

I have tried the following iptables string matching rule :

iptables -A INPUT -m string --string "1.1.1.1" --algo bm --to 1024 -j DROP

However this doesn't seem to do anything.

Why isn't the string matching working ? I'm sure the real ip is sent in the packet , either as X-Forwarded-For or CF-Connecting-IP.

Kernel is 3.4.x and iptables 1.4.7, so no issues there .

Comment: This is my iptables file :

Comment: This may help: `iptables -I INPUT -m string --algo bm --string "1.1.1.1" -j DROP` (-I instead of -A) -- if you have other rules, this one will become the 1st rule to check.

Answer (score 0):

As you mention CF-Connecting-IP is the best way to get the real IP behind CloudFlare. This is better than X-Forwarded-For as that can be changed if your server is then placed behind a load balancer or another reverse proxy (X-Forwarded-For even supports a comma separated list in it's RFC).

CloudFlare should only pass secure traffic and only web traffic to [CloudFlare supported web server ports](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169156-Which-ports-will-CloudFlare-work-with-), therefore you can whitelist [CloudFlare IPs](https://www.cloudflare.com/ips) and enable IPTables on other IPs. You can then block IPs in the Firewall tab of the CloudFlare site in question, then looking under IP Firewall. Non-CloudFlare traffic can then have IPTables applied to it.

We use the official [Mod_CloudFlare](https://www.cloudflare.com/resources-downloads#mod_cloudflare) on our Apache servers in order to correctly get the IP Address to our web server and ultimately into the web application itself. On NGinX you can try the [ngx_http_realip_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_realip_module.html).

Comment: Essentially, it is best to block IPs at a CloudFlare level. If you want to do this programatically (e.g. with Fail2Ban), it is best to use the official API.

Comment: I already am blocking ips at cloudflare level but their API is limited and there's a maximum quota for number of ips.

I want to block ips at kernel level and my question is specifically about iptables string matching, but thanks for your suggestion anyway.

Comment: Could you try: iptables -A INPUT -m string --algo bm --string "1.1.1.1" -j DROP